# Centre of osculating circle

Tags: multivariable-calculus

> Show that the centre of the osculating circle for the parabola y = x$^2$ at the point (a,a$^2$) is located at (-4a$^3$, 3a$^2$ + 1/2).

I've got no idea how to get started. I would know exactly what to do if x and y were given as functions of t, then get **T**  and **N** to get to the centre.
Velocity is 2x, and how do you get |v|? How would you go about doing this?

Thank you for help.

Comment: Your  information "Velocity is $2x$" I would interpret such that the norm of the velocity vector at $(x,y)$ is $2x$. Is that what was intended?

Comment: Alas this would lead to a complicated expression for $x$ in terms of $t$.

Answer (score 2):

$r(t)=(x(t), y(t)) = (t, t^2)$ is a parametrization of many possible ones with $y(t) = x(t)^2$.

Note that this choice makes a choice of the resulting velocity as well.

$\lVert v \rVert$ looks like the norm of the velocity vector $v = \dot{r} = (\dot{x}, \dot{y})$. It is 
$$
\lVert v \rVert^2 = \dot{x}^2 + \dot{y}^2 = (1 + (dy/dx)^2))\, \dot{x}^2
$$